# Xamarin Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have installed Visual Studio 2015

I want use xamarion in c#
I have reinstall vs2015 and checked xamarin but get error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxm6T.png)
I try modified install from control panel but not success
Thanks

Xamarin in visual studio 2015 error

Comment: 404 means the problem is on Microsoft's side, [VS2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2015) should still be supported so hopefully they'll fix the issue at some point.

Comment: Having said that, any particular reason you need such an archaic version?

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have update 3 version. So if i use 2019 version the problem will be solved or not??

Comment: I would go for the latest - Visual Studio 2022, which comes with Xamarin support built in.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

i Just use VS 2019
you can use it or higher version because 2015 not supported
Thank's

Comment: Glad you solved this question and thanks for sharing your solution with the community!

Comment: By the way, why not use the latest VS 2022?